# Rename the DataSet in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have the code below (written in VB.Net) to try to rename the `DataSet` after its declaration but it's not working. The data set is maintaining its generic name ( which is "`Table`").  Does anybody have an idea why it's not changing the name of the `DataSet`?

```
Dim ds As New DataSet With {
        .DataSetName = "data"
    }
```

This is how I am converting the DataSet result to JSON:

```
Dim myJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings With { .ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() })
```

However, the result has "table" instead of "data"

```
{

  "table": [
  {
    "Column1": "John",
    "Column2": "49",
  },
```

Comment: Code works for me.  Maybe we need to see more code in how you are using it.

Comment: Your suggestion changes the DataSet name, however, it's not keeping the new name when I convert its result to JSON. Here is what the result looks like.    {
  "table": [
    {
      "Column1": "John",
      "Column2": "49",
    } . I want the result to say "data" instead of "table"

Comment: You would have to post your JSON conversion code into your question.  BTW, I get "NewDataSet" as default DataSetName, not "Table".

Comment: Dim myJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings With {
                                .ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                                })

Comment: I suspect that that is the name of a `DataTable` in the `DataSet` rather than the name of the `DataSet` itself.

Comment: Set the DataSet and DataTable names after they are populated.  Otherwise they get renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `DataTable` instead to get your desired result like below :

```
Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim table1 As DataTable = New DataTable("data")
table1.Columns.Add("Column1")
table1.Columns.Add("Column2")
table1.Rows.Add("John", 49)

ds.Tables.Add(table1)

Dim myJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings With {.ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()})
```

**Output**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "column1": "John",
      "column2": "49"
    }
  ]
}
```

When converting the `DataSet` to Json, name of the `DataTables` of that `DataSet` is used to generate the Json data.

Comment: Thanks @ Md. Suman Kabir for your answer -- it's working now, however, I am using SqlServerAdapter (adapter) to fill my dataset (adapter.Fill(ds)) instead of adding rows the way you did. But, your answer put me on the right track to figure out what else needs to be done. Thanks!

Comment: My answer was pretty much the same but i got downvoted coff coff

Answer (score 2):

Just for more information. I found another way to do what I was trying to do -- see the code below.

```
       'Declaring the string for the JSON file
        Dim myJson As String = String.Empty

       'Checking if the dataset is empty or not
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            ds.Tables(0).TableName = "data"
            'Converting the dataset result to JSON
            myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings With {
                            .ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                            })
        End If
```